# Is it possible to change allowed memory in php.ini for a single page?

Tags: php, apache, drupal

Is there a way to set the allowed memory for a single page? I don't want to allow other pages to exceed 128m when requested but there is one page that will give me a 500 error if I have the allowed memory size in php.ini set to 128m or lower.

Comment: I think yo want this `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 1):

even better check out this module that does it for you using config: http://drupal.org/project/path_memory

Answer (score 0):

Create a second php.ini file for the other page.  And create a rule in your apache config to use that ini file for that page request only

Comment: ini_set is by far the better way to go here. creating a seperate file for every page is dirty and error prone.